# Mat Table Redirects to Root

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've a project based on `angular v6`, the problem is whenever I try to use mat table in any of a component that component simply redirects to root and no error is there in developer tools console.

When ever I hit the vehicle-temp route it redirects me to the root page and although nothing seems wrong in the code but I'm not able to figure out the issue.

Here is my Component

My Module

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

const routes: Routes = [{path: 'vehicles-temp', component: VehicleHistoryDetailsDialogComponent}];

@NgModule({

  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    BrowserModule,
    MatTableModule
  ],

  declarations: [
    VehicleHistoryDetailsDialogComponent
  ],

  exports: [
    VehicleHistoryDetailsDialogComponent
  ],

})

export class VehicleHistoryModule {}
```

My Template

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="[]">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="operation_name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Operation</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.operation_name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="ro_number">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>RO #</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.ro_number}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="repair_shop_location">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Location</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.repair_shop_location}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.status}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
```

App Router

```
`
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'login/:profile_id', component: AuthLoginComponent},
  {path: 'signup', component: SignUpComponent},
  {path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent},
  {path: 'reset-password/:token', component: ResetPasswordComponent},
  {path: 'inventory', component: InventoryListComponent, canActivate: [UserService], data: {id: 'inventory_enabled'}},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [UserService], data: {id: 'dashboard_enabled'}},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'ros', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
`
```

UPDATE: if comment out the table the redirection stops

Comment: Please show your router configuration and the component in which you are using mat-tables.

Comment: I've updated the question with code

Comment: This is just a part of your router configuration and also the component class would be helpful to see.

Comment: Component is empty just @Component Decorator is all

Comment: added root router module too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, the issue was in tsconfig I was using `"target": "es2016"`. switching it to `es5` it started working again.